# Black and Scholes Implied Volatility estimation via rootsolving

Tags: matlab, solver

A subquestion of my assignment requires to compute the implied volatility σ via the Black and Scholes option valuation formula which is:

[image: BS Formula]

More specifically, it requires to solve the equation numerically via rootsolving for σ when all parameters have given values.

I am trying to use the `fzero` function of MATLAB in order to estimate σ. I created two scripts.

The fist script includes:

```
S_0 = 1403; % Stock Price
K = 1350    ;  % Strike Price 
rf = 0.0534; % Risk Free Rate 
div=0.0118; % Divident Rate
T=0.1028; % Maturity Period
C=81;% Call option value
fixed_input=[S_0,K,rf,div,T,C];% Construct vector input values
save ('fixed_input.mat','fixed_input');
imp_vol_ini=0.1; % Initial Implied Volatility Value
BlackScholes = @BSF;
[imp_vol,y]=fzero(BlackScholes,imp_vol_ini)
```

While the second script includes the code:

```
function y=BSF(imp_vol)
load fixed_input
S_0=fixed_input(1);
K=fixed_input(2);
rf=fixed_input(3);
div=fixed_input(4);
T=fixed_input(5);
C=fixed_input(6);
d1_nominator=log(S_0/K)+(rf-div+(imp_vol^2)/2)*T;
d1_denominator=imp_vol*sqrt(T);
d1=d1_nominator/d1_denominator;
d2=d1-imp_vol*sqrt(T);
y=C-(exp(-div*T))*S_0*normcdf(d1)+K*(exp(-rf/T))*normcdf(d2);
end
```

The code works but the numbers are not reasonable. Normally, after the solving, `y` should be close to zero while `σ` should lie between the interval [0.1 , 0.3] but this is not the case. The numbers that I retrieve are `y=81` while `σ=-2.7018e-16`.

I sense that this has something to do with the constraints and the options of the `fzero`. Can you please help me?

Comment: give that guy a medal!!! Thanks a lot! works perfectly!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama: Do you know how can I avoid the save and load part and pass the fixed values (S_0, K etc.) through, `BlackScholes = @BSF;
[imp_vol,y]=fzero(BlackScholes,imp_vol_ini)` by keeping them stable and optimizing only the σ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the last line of `BSF` function which is:

```
y=C-(exp(-div*T))*S_0*normcdf(d1)+K*(exp(-rf/T))*normcdf(d2)‌​;
%                                           ↑
```

You wrote a `/` instead of `*`. It should've been this: ‍‍‍‍‍‍

```
y=C-(exp(-div*T))*S_0*normcdf(d1)+K*(exp(-rf*T))*normcdf(d2)‌​;
%                                           ↑
```

Comment: Just curious, how do you make those nice looking arrows?

Comment: @Cebri  hah   `Alt + 24` (24 from the NumPad) makes `↑`